# Scala Lift - Delete file in mongo gridfs

Tags: scala, mongodb, lift, gridfs

I'm trying to find the correct method of deleting a file from mongodb gridfs.

Would the standard query suffice?

```
record.delete_!
```

Or is there a specific way of doing it properly?

Thanks in advance, any help much appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

GridFS doesn't store files as records. GridFS gives you handle to stored file that spans more than one document (in order to exceed document size limits). To delete file in GridFS you have to use its API. So in order to delete file you have to find it, for example using this method:
http://api.mongodb.org/java/2.9.1/com/mongodb/gridfs/GridFS.html#find(org.bson.types.ObjectId)
Then when you have reference to file you can delete it. Example code might look like:

```
MongoDB.use(DefaultMongoIdentifier) { db =>
  val fs = new GridFS(db)
  fs.remove(gridFsId.is)
}
```

gridFsId is ObjectId stored in Lift record that keeps handle to file in GridFS.
I hope that helps.